# quarkus resteasy-jackson empty json result for native

Tags: quarkus

Testing **quarkus** app, with my rest endpoint /init

Installed features: [cdi, resteasy, resteasy-jackson]

I found that when run app as java (not native), then check
http://localhost:8080/init

```
{
"user": {
"username": "u name",
"firstName": "f name",
"lastName": "l name",
"email": null
},
"logoutUrl": "url!!!!"
}
```

and as native,

And running native-ly like this:
package -Dnative -f pom.xml

Then run ./my-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:

it gets **empty** result:
http://localhost:8080/init

```
{}
```

The Jackson configure like this:

```
    @Singleton
public class RegisterCustomModuleCustomizer implements ObjectMapperCustomizer {

    public void customize(final ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
    }
}
```

No exception.

InitData defined like this, as normal bean class:

```
    public class InitData {

        private .. some fields
```

What could be missing? In't it supposed to works same for native/java?

---

**UPDATE**:

when run as java, compile quarkus:dev -f pom.xml:

> [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO]  [INFO] ------------<
>   my.compnay:my-service >------------ [INFO] Building my-service
>   1.0-SNAPSHOT [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]--------------------------------- [INFO]  [INFO] ---
>   maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ my-service
>   --- [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources. [INFO] Copying 1 resource [INFO]  [INFO] ---
>   maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ my-service ---
>   [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! [INFO] Compiling 41
>   source files to
>   /home/me/projects/my-project/v2/my-service-quarkus/target/classes
>   [INFO]  [INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:1.0.0.CR1:dev (default-cli) @
>   my-service --- Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
>   2019-11-12 14:17:43,027 INFO  [io.qua.dep.QuarkusAugmentor] (main)
>   Beginning quarkus augmentation 2019-11-12 14:17:43,599 INFO 
>   [io.qua.arc.pro.BeanProcessor] (build-1) Found unrecommended usage of
>   private members (use package-private instead) in application beans:
>     - @Inject field my.compnay.application.InitResource#initFacadeService 2019-11-12 14:17:43,658 INFO  [io.qua.dep.QuarkusAugmentor] (main)
>   Quarkus augmentation completed in 631ms 2019-11-12 14:17:44,104 INFO 
>   [io.quarkus] (main) Quarkus 1.0.0.CR1 started in 1.260s. Listening on:
>   http://0.0.0.0:8080 2019-11-12 14:17:44,105 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main)
>   Profile dev activated. Live Coding activated. 2019-11-12 14:17:44,105
>   INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [cdi, resteasy,
>   resteasy-jackson]

Then hit: http://localhost:8080/init

> 2019-11-12 14:19:52,423 INFO  [com.dis.pla.app.ser.fil.LoggingFilter]
>   (vert.x-worker-thread-1) Request GET /init from IP
>   0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:48810 2019-11-12 14:19:52,425 INFO 
>   [com.dis.pla.app.InitResource] (vert.x-worker-thread-1) Init with user
>   f name my.compnay.api.UserData@37ac6925

--

Comment: A wild guess, but are you running Jandex on the project that contains `InitData`? Are you getting any warnings when running quarkus:dev about this class?

Comment: not sure about Jandex, will check (it is based on hello-world example). but updated the question. added the log for java case.

Comment: No, no warning about the `InitData` in the log. I don't know.

Comment: Can we see what your JAX-RS endpoint looks like?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`@RegisterForReflection` (from [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started#bootstrapping-the-project)) is the annotation to use over the Data objects IF your Resource doe snot return that data object directly.

I.e. in my case:

```
  @GET
    public Response getInit(
```

thus it would not work innately until you put:

```
@RegisterForReflection
class InitData { ...
```

But still.

I think I should be a bug. It should all behave same way. Native or not.

Comment: fixed my problem, thank you! It makes me wonder, as i have 15 almost identical Resource classes and all of them works fine, except this one. For me the only difference is that most are the JPA @Entity, while this one wasn't. It makes me wonder if annotating all Dto's should not be a common practise (which i did not found in the Quarkus Docs) until fixed differently.

Answer (score 5):

I also thought it was a bug, but they explain it better [here (`quarkus.io`)](https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips#registering-for-reflection):

> When building a native executable, GraalVM operates with a closed world assumption. It analyzes the call tree and removes all the classes/methods/fields that are not used directly.
>
> The elements used via reflection are not part of the call tree so they are dead code eliminated (if not called directly in other cases). To include these  elements in your native executable, you need to register them for reflection explicitly.